# Windows 7: After reinstall, other partions remain write protected

Tags: windows-7

After reinstalling Windows 7 (format and reinstall on `C:\`), I cannot copy files (from e.g. USB sticks) to the other partions made with the first Win 7 installation. Removing the read attribute doesnt help, and I cannot find any solution.

With Windows Explorer I get an error `Error 0x80070570: the file or directory is corrupted and unreadable`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you REMOVED the read attribute, then the system will not be able to read it.  If you want to make it writeable, you need to ADD the write attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is already a write attribute for the partition ...